# In an Ember `.findRecord` promise, variable from parent scope must be cloned?

Tags: ember.js, scope, promise, ember-data, es6-promise

I am sending an plain old javascript object up with through an action to my route file.

In the route file, I am then fetching a record to update it.
The [`.findRecord()` method](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/models/creating-updating-and-deleting-records/#toc_updating-records) returns a resolved promise.
However, when inside the `.then` my variable declared in the parent scope outside of the `then` is an empty object.

routes/task.js

```
export default Route.extend({
  model (params) {
    const id = params.task_id
    return this.get('store').findRecord('task', id)
  },
  actions: {
    saveNotes (updatedTask) {

      // updatedTask is the expected object {name: "New Name}
      console.log(`updatedTask outside is:`, updatedTask);

      this.get('store').findRecord('task', taskID).then(task => {

        // updatedTask is an empty object {}
        console.log(`updatedTask inside is:`, updatedTask);

        task.setProperties(updatedTask)
        task.save()
      })
    }
  }
});
```

However, if I clone the object, then the value is correct.

routes/task.js

```
export default Route.extend({
  model (params) {
    const id = params.task_id
    return this.get('store').findRecord('task', id)
  },
  actions: {
    saveNotes (updatedTask) {

      // updatedTask is the expected object {name: "New Name}
      console.log(`updatedTask outside is:`, updatedTask);

      let clone = Object.assign({}, updatedTask)

      this.get('store').findRecord('task', taskID).then(task => {

        // clone is the expected object {name: "New Name}
        console.log(`clone inside is:`, clone);

        task.setProperties(updatedTask)
        task.save()
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: try to `Object.freeze` your object. I strongly assume you have some code that changes this object while the promise resolves.

Comment: Check the code, where your action "saveNotes" is triggered.

Comment: Please post the triggering code.